# check if view is currently animating

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

Is there a way to check if there is an animation running on a specific view? like a property that return true if the specific view is currently animating and false if it is not. The view is animated with `UIView.animateWithDuration` methods

I am animating a constraint on a view and at random times some event will occur that will trigger another animation. I would like to trigger the second animation only after the first animation finishes animating.